# equivalent of "$" in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to.  How would I get an attribute of an R object in rpy2?  For example, what's the equivalent of the R code: `m$eval` in rpy2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For R lists, `$` is equivalent to `[[` with a vector of length 1: `foo$bar` is equivalent to `foo[["bar"]]`. With rpy2 this would be `foo.rx2('bar')`, or `foo[foo.index('bar')]` (See [extracting element, R-style](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html?highlight=subset#extracting-r-style)).